# How to compare the distributions of two variables

Tags: distributions, data-visualization, median, boxplot

The attached figure plots the distributions of two variables.

I want to demonstrate statistically how closely the the two distributions match each other. What is the best way of doing this?

[image]

Comment: How many points do you have ?

Comment: "best" in what sense? What are you trying to be best *at*? (what makes one thing better than another for your purposes?) Do you have the individual data points in both samples?

Answer (score 1):

There might not be a *best* solution as such. But if you are trying to visualize the distribution similarity, you can use violin plots instead of box-plots.

However, if statistical measures of similarity is what you are trying to calculate, then I think you should try fitting the distributions against several standard distributions and see how well they compare. If you are familiar with **GLD**s (Generalized Lambda Distributions), you can obtain GLD fits for each of the distributions and compare their resulting parameters.

Comment: Not familiar with GLDs I'm afraid. I'm wondering...might comparing their distributions with chi-squared be an option?

Comment: It might not be the best option. But yes, it is an option. It all depends on how good a measure you require.

Answer (score 1):

To compare two distributions you have several options.

First of all you can visualize the two distributions:

- plot the probability density functions
- plot the cumulative distribution functions
- a quantile-quantile plot

Then, you can statistically characterize the differences between the two distributions:

- run statistical hypothesis tests to check whether there is a significant difference between the two samples; in your case (distributions seem to be a bit skewed) you should rely on non-parametric Mann-Whitney or Kolmogorov-Smirnov test (if you don't know how such tests work, you can find nice explanations on CrossValidated)
- compute [Kullback–Leibler divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) (and similar measures)

In particular, Kullback-Leibler divergence is a non-symmetric measure of the difference between two probability distributions, say $P$ and $Q$. More precisely, the KS divergence of $Q$ to $P$, $D_{KL}(P||Q)$, is a measure of the information lost when $Q$ is used to approximate $P$.

For discrete probability distributions $P$ and $Q$, the KS divergence is defined as:
$$D_{KL}(P||Q) = \sum_{i}P(i) \ln \frac{P(i)}{Q(i)}, $$
whereas in the continuous case:
$$D_{KL}(P||Q) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(x) \ln \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}dx,$$

where $p$ and $q$ represent the densities of $P$ and $Q$.

Note that the KS divergence is always non-negative: $D_{KL}(P||Q)  \geq 0$, and the equality holds if and only if $P = Q$ [almost everywhere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere).

Comment: I'm afraid the estimate of Kullback-Leibler based on two samples is not an easy thing to deal with.

Comment: I guess it depends on the size of the two samples...

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Kullback-Leibler divergence (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback_Leibler_divergence). This describes the loss of information when one distribution is used to approximate the other

Comment: I think @luciano has one sample of each distribution, he does not have the distributions themsleves. And I'm afraid the estimate of Kullback-Leibler based on two samples is not an easy thing to deal with.